# how to override an open var in a fileprivate extension

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, how to override an open var in a fileprivate extension, or is there any way to achieve the goal?

There is a table view in a view controller, when I touch a button, the property of `isUserInteractionEnabled` will be set opposite, then the alpha of the table view will change according to the `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

And I want to use property observation, overriding `isUserInteractionEnabled` in a `UITableView` extension

```
fileprivate extension UITableView {
    open override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            alpha = isUserInteractionEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.6
        }
    }
}
```

The code embeds in a UIViewController, I want this extension just takes effect inside this view controller. But it turns out it does not work. This extension takes effect everywhere I use a `UITableView`.

How should I override the `isUserInteractionEnabled` in extension and make it just take effect in specific file. I am avoiding writing code like below, it seems painful to maintain.

```
tableView.alpha = 0.6
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: That's how extensions work; they modify the class. You could subclass UITableView and override the behaviour in that subclass and then use that subclass in the one view controller where you need it.

Comment: @Paulw11Thank you. I just wondered whether there is a way works like the Category in Objective-C, where Category takes effect only when imported

Comment: @Monsoir: Overriding existing properties in an Objective-C category is (and always was) undefined behavior.

Comment: @MartinR  Thanks for reminding